# How do I stub a view in rspec-2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm in the process of upgrading an app to Rails 3/Rspec 2.  I see that
stubbing a view helper method has changed in Rspec 2.  It looks like
instead of doing template.stub!, we're now supposed to do view.stub!,
but I can't seem to get this to work on beta 10.  I get an "undefined
local variable or method `view' for # < RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x106785fd0>"
error.

I see that in [this commit](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/commit/0e860f580618045a34c17069b308c093e2e830cb) David removed the view
method, but I can't figure out what it was replaced with.  Something
in ActionView::TestCase::Behavior?

I'm on rails 3.0.0.beta3.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in rspec-rails after moving more of the functionality back to ActionView::TestCase::Behavior.  David re-exposed _view as view, so view.stub! is still the way to go.  It was just temporarily broken.